# Moving button programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i have a problem moving a button in C#. I have thinking so many times. And i haven't figured out what is the problem with my code. If you guys can find out where are my mistakes, please help me. Thank you so much before.

here is my method that supposed to move a button when arrow keys is pressed.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 39)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
    else if (e.KeyValue == 37)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to provide a solution when there is no a description of the problem. You say you have a problem, but not what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the arrow keys are kind of special keys that are automatically handled by Controls.  So, you could handle pressing arrow keys in one of these ways:

**First way**:

I suggest you to use `ProcessCmdKey` without handling any `key` events:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            pad.Location = new Point(pad.Location.X - 1, pad.Location.Y);
            return true; 
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            pad.Location = new Point(pad.Location.X + 1, pad.Location.Y);
            return true; 
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

---

**Second way:**

But if you want to use events for solving this problem you can use `KeyUp` event instead of the `KeyDown` event.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BringToFront();
    this.Focus();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyValue == 39)
    {
        pad.Location = new Point(pad.Location.X + 1, pad.Location.Y);
    }
    else if (e.KeyValue == 37)
    {
        pad.Location = new Point(pad.Location.X - 1, pad.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;

            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);


        }
   void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
         if (e.KeyValue == 39)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
    else if (e.KeyValue == 37)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
 }
```

try this